# How to install openCV without pip to python?

Tags: python, opencv, pip

I tried `pip install cv2` and `pip install open_cv` and got the same problem - a warning message from dist.py and complains about zlib being not found. No cv2 installed. I also tried pyopenvc and `pip install opencv-python`.

So, I went to the opencv site and downloaded the relevant exe. Ran it - generated a heap of subdirectories and a make file and stuff.

What do I do now?

Comment: can you share the warning messages you received :) ?

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting? You can download the library manually and put it in Python library folder by yourself.

Comment: don't mess around. the package is called `opencv-python` and `pip install opencv-python` is supposed to work. if your installation of python is broken (complaining about zlib), that is **not** an opencv problem. you need to completely remove and clean up all your python installations, then start fresh, and install a single python.

Comment: @AndroidYemenApp. "Ran it - generated a heap of subdirectories and a make file and stuff.".  It worked for me. I went into python's folder and select filename, and run it. That took me about 2 minutes.